# SQL DML: Incorrect date value (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, insert-into, date-format, dml

I created a table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE official_receipt(
    student_no INT UNSIGNED,
    academic_year CHAR(8),
    trimester ENUM('1', '2', '3'),
    or_no MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED,
    issue_date DATE NOT NULL,
    received_from VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    amount_of DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    issued_by VARCHAR(255),
    doc_type ENUM('FULL', 'DOWN', 'INST') NOT NULL,
    form_of_payment ENUM('CASH', 'INST') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (student_no, academic_year, trimester, or_no)
);
```

I inserted some values:

```
INSERT INTO official_receipt(student_no , academic_year, trimester, or_no, issue_date, received_from, amount_of, issued_by, doc_type, form_of_payment)
VALUES
    (201201121, 'AY201314', '1', 029940, 2013-05-21, 'NAME', 20000.00, NULL, 'DOWN', 'INST'),
    (201201121, 'AY201314', '1', 029944, 2013-07-23, 'NAME', 8000.00, NULL, 'INST', 'INST'),
    (201201101, 'AY201314', '1', 029941, 2013-05-21, 'NAME', 56650.00, NULL, 'FULL', 'CASH'),
    (201201037, 'AY201314', '1', 029942, 2013-05-21, 'NAME', 56650.00, NULL, 'FULL', 'CASH'),
    (201201142, 'AY201314', '1', 029943, 2013-05-21, 'NAME', 63800.00, NULL, 'FULL', 'CASH');
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '1987' for column 'issue_date' at row 1
```

I am quite stumped because I already followed the YYYY-MM-DD format. Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As documented under [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.

Therefore, the expression `2013-05-21` is not a valid MySQL date literal (it is in fact an arithmetic expression, consisting of two subtractions: it results in the integer `1987`).  In order to comply with one of the literal formats detailed above, you must either quote your date literal as a string and/or remove the delimiters.

Comment: It is barely apparent you're talking about missing quotes here.

Comment: @ebyrob: That's because I'm not.  There's a perfectly valid literal format for dates which does not require quotes: in this case one merely need remove the delimiters.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing with `'` single quotes around the `issue_date` values for my test it inserts the records successfully

Try this

```
INSERT INTO official_receipt(student_no , academic_year, trimester, or_no, issue_date, received_from, amount_of, issued_by, doc_type, form_of_payment)
VALUES
    (201201121, 'AY201314', '1', 029940, '2013-05-21', 'NAME', 20000.00, NULL, 'DOWN', 'INST'),
    (201201121, 'AY201314', '1', 029944, '2013-07-23', 'NAME', 8000.00, NULL, 'INST', 'INST'),
    (201201101, 'AY201314', '1', 029941, '2013-05-21', 'NAME', 56650.00, NULL, 'FULL', 'CASH'),
    (201201037, 'AY201314', '1', 029942, '2013-05-21', 'NAME', 56650.00, NULL, 'FULL', 'CASH'),
    (201201142, 'AY201314', '1', 029943, '2013-05-21', 'NAME', 63800.00, NULL, 'FULL', 'CASH');
```

[**Here is your fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8336e/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. That web app is very useful too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the date literal in quotes. The error message says `1987` because the unquoted date is being read as the expression `2013 minus 5 minus 21`, which is `1987`.

Your dates can be like this: `'2013-05-21'` or `'20130521'` or a couple other formats covered in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html).